# Authenticity of host can’t be established. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, ssh, circleci

i am trying to connect to my EC2 instance from CircleCI but i keep getting this error.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to fix this all you need to do is:

1. Go to amazon and copy the "**Public DNS (IPv4)**" entire string
2. Before calling the `ssh` connection add this line:

   ```
   ssh-keyscan 'ec2-x-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
   ```

   this will whitelist your host
3. And finally you can log into the ssh

   ```
   ssh -t ec2-user@ec2-x-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
   ```

ps: replace the x with the numbers from your ip

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Comment: off topic why? i lost time searching for this, and want to share it. if you know the answer than answer or ignore it

Comment: also jww you have 54,223 REPUTATION. in the world are people with real problems that need answers and help. you are just seeking bounties to increase your score. this is exactly what is wrong with stackoverflow.

Comment: Stack Overlow has a lot of problems. Me being a rep whȯre is not one of them. If you look at the close reason, you will find folks are suggesting the question is on-topic at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Do you know the purpose of Stack Overflow, and why the question was off-topic?

Comment: there was no where to find a good answer for my problem. Since i am, like many many in the world, a noob in some things, googling for 10 minutes was not enough. it took me hours. if something sould be on other stack domain, it should be the stack wh°re moving it, instead of downvoting it. yeahhh, the technology is not here yet